# Reportlab: Understanding multiBuild()

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

> **Cross post**: I posted [this question](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!topic/reportlab-users/Qewu0gzz_bI) in the reportlab group, but haven't got a reply so far.

I read a bit through docs and code and am interested in the mechanics of `multiBuild()`.

From what I understand, it offers me to build a document in multiple passes. During a pass I can use the `notify()` method to inform some listeners.

The information gathered in one pass can be used in a following pass to create output based on this information. One example implementation is `TableOfContents()` which needs a first pass to analyze the structure of the content and based on that (in a second pass?) is able to render out the TOC.

If I am correct so far, then e.g. one use case of `multiBuild()` could be to in a first run render all the content, and on a second pass render a page counter like `Page 2 of X`, a `word and character-count` or what not.

How would a very simple implementation of this (just the boilerplate) look like, preferably in a class that extends `BaseDocTemplate`?

1. Where would I call `notify()` to increase a counter on any page (`handle_pageEnd()`?),
2. how and where would I access information gathered from the first pass in the second pass to render out new information,
3. how and where would I tell the script that after that second pass all requirements are satisfied?

I am thankful for your help.